# Accessing the parent activity from the current activity

Tags: android, android-activity, scroll, webview

I am implementing two activities- one is a webview activity and the other one is a pin-lock activity which shows a pin lock. The webview activity calls the pin-lock activity which locks the screen until the user enters the correct PIN. I would like to know how can I enable scrolling on my web-view even if the PIN-lock activity is shown.

The idea is to allow the user to scroll the webview for a few seconds (say 5 sec) after the Pin-lock appears and then disable the scrolling (after 5 sec). How can I enable the scrolling feature in the parent activity which calls the current activity i.e. the PIN-lock activity?

[image: Screenshot of the two activities- webview activity which calls the current activity- PIN-lock activity]

Comment: Use a callback scheme to make the parent activity do something rather than access it directly.

Comment: Make your pin lock activity transparent but occupies the whole screen, then the parent activity will not receive any touch events

Comment: If those are truly two activities, you can't. Only one activity can be active. You'll need to use a FrameLayout to superimpose the transparent pin-lock UI over your webview.

Comment: I am planning to implement my Pin-Lock program as a library so that anyone implementing a webview or any other view can call the library upon request and lock the screen. Is there a way where I can add the calling parent activity as a fragment?